# not able to execute java file

Tags: java, cron

I am creating a simple Cron Scheduler. I am working without IDE so the file is not compiling

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
public class CronJob implements Job{

public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Regular");
    SendRegular sR = new SendRegular();
    sR.Reglar();
    System.out.println("Reappear");
    SendReappear SR = new SendReappear();
    SR.Reapp();
   }
}
```

This is the code which I am compiling

```
java CronSched
```

this is the way I am running the code and I am getting the following error

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and 
try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/quartz/ScheduleBuilder
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.q 
uartz.ScheduleBuilder
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Where is it wrong??

Answer (score 0):

```
 javac -cp ".:/home/aditya/CronSched/CronSched/lib/quartz-2.2.3/lib/quartz-2.2.3.jar" CronJob.java
```

don't compile two quartz file the, IDE will accept it but the termical compilation won't accept

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples for using javac -cp on the command line:

http://dev.datalogics.com/pdf-java-toolkit/getting-started-guide/compiling-and-running-sample-programs-with-java-commands/

Note that there are no spaces in the list of jars and no double quotes needed.